# GNU Make correct behaviour when including other makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following makefile in the root of the project:

Makefile

```
# Board version
# Available: 3
PI              ?= 3

# Kernel binaries
ifeq ($(PI), 3)
KERNEL_IMG      := kernel8.img
else ifeq ($(PI), 2)
KERNEL_IMG      := kernel7.img
else ifeq ($(PI), 1)
KERNEL_IMG      := kernel.img
else
$(error Unsupported Raspberry Pi version)
endif

KERNEL_ELF      := $(patsubst %.img,%.elf,$(KERNEL_IMG))

# Directories/paths
BUILD_DIR       := build

# Toolchain
TOOLCHAIN       ?= aarch64-elf
OBJCOPY         := $(TOOLCHAIN)-objcopy
LD              := $(TOOLCHAIN)-ld
CC              := $(TOOLCHAIN)-gcc

# Misc
LINKER_SCRIPT   := linker.ld

# Flags
LDFLAGS         := -T $(LINKER_SCRIPT)
ASFLAGS         :=
CFLAGS          :=

# Source files
C_SRC           := $(wildcard *.c)
ASM_SRC         := $(wildcard *.S)

# Include
include pi/$(PI)/mod.mk

# Object files
OBJECTS         := $(patsubst %,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$(C_SRC))
OBJECTS         += $(patsubst %,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$(ASM_SRC))

# Targets
.PHONY: all builddirs clean
all: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(KERNEL_IMG)

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(KERNEL_IMG): $(BUILD_DIR)/$(KERNEL_ELF)
        $(OBJCOPY) $< -O binary $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(KERNEL_ELF): $(LINKER_SCRIPT) $(OBJECTS)
        $(LD) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

$(OBJECTS): | builddirs

builddirs: $(BUILD_DIR)/pi/$(PI)

$(BUILD_DIR)/pi/$(PI):
        mkdir -p $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.S.o: %.S
        $(CC) -c $< $(ASFLAGS) -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@

clean:
        $(RM) -r $(BUILD_DIR)
```

It includes pi/3/mod.mk

```
C_SRC           +=
ASM_SRC         += pi/3/start.S

$(BUILD_DIR)/pi/3/start.S.o: pi/3/start.S pi/3/include/cpu/sysregs.h
        $(CC) -c $< $(ASFLAGS) -o $@
```

Now here's the problem: whenever I run 'make' in the root of a project, '$(BUILD_DIR)/pi/3/start.S.o' rule invokes, instead of 'all'. If I move 'include pi/$(PI)/mod.mk' to the very bottom of the root makefile, and replace 'C_SRC' and 'ASM_SRC' variables in 'pi/3/mod.mk' with 'OBJECTS += $(BUILD_DIR)/pi/3/start.S.o' and invoke 'make', this rule isn't even invoked, so I get an error that make doesn't know how to build start.S.o.

What am I doing wrong and what is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make's default goal is the first target in your Makefile. In your case the first target is the one defined in the included Makefile: `$(BUILD_DIR)/pi/3/start.S.o`. Either invoke `make all` or move the `all` rule in your Makefile such that it becomes the first one, or tell make that the default goal is `all`:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
```

(see [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Variables)).